# Why is there that watermark on th top left corner of the image?

Tags: html, image

I don't have a transparent image or anything so why is there that watermark on the top left corner of the img?

[image]

```html
<img style="display:inline-block;background-color:#000000; width: 256px; height: 256px; cursor: pointer; border: 5px solid #000000;" onClick="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/M5VkVbK.png'
    this.style.width='266px';this.style.height='266px'
    ;this.style.cursor='default'" />
```

Just curious about this. Hoping someone on here will have an answer.

Comment: That looks like a broken image link symbol, not a watermark

Comment: Nothing wrong with the image: https://i.imgur.com/M5VkVbK.png works fine.

Comment: Yes, but you're applying the url only after clicking the image. *Before* the click the image is broken because it doesn't have a src attribute.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a watermark, that means it can't find the image. Double check your URL, and ensure that your development machine can access that URL.

The code seems to work fine for me here.

Note that before you click, you will have the broken image icon because the `<img>` tag does not have its `src` defined. A good work-around would be to use a 1x1 image in the meantime. I'm implemented this in my snippet below.

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/1" style="display:inline-block;background-color:#000000; width: 256px; height: 256px; cursor: pointer; border: 5px solid #000000;"
onClick="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/M5VkVbK.png'
this.style.width='266px';this.style.height='266px'
;this.style.cursor='default'"/>
```

Comment: @assaassa, Glad it worked. Don't forget to click the checkmark under the arrows on the left when you're able. :)